# Скоро свет увидит новую линейку видеокарт RTX 50 серии и у меня по этому поводу есть вопрос к знатокам

Tags: видеокарта, пк, материнская-плата

На новых версиях RTX 50 серии обещают память ГДДР 7. Хватит ли пропускной способности PCIe 5.0 на моей материнке чтобы использовать видеокарты 50 серии без ограничений или придется ждать уже новый PCIe 6.0? Просто хочу в будущем обновить только видеокарту, поэтому интересно, смогу ли запихнуть новое поколение или придется полностью менять материнку, а вместе с тем процессор и тд. (Если надо, то материнка ASUS ROG STRIX B760-F)

Comment: Пропускная способность PCIe не имеет никакого отношения к пропускной способности видеопамяти, и сейчас даже старенького PCIe 3.0 более чем достаточно для большинства задач (а иногда даже PCIe 2.0 хватает)

Comment: Значит я спокойно смогу поставить новое поколение видеокарт на свою материнку и они будут работать в полную силу? Просто я думал, что пропускной способности PCIe 5.0 может не хватить для новой ГДДР7

Comment: `или придется полностью менять` только если при этом устроят треш с обрезанием кол-ва линий. ну как у красных был в затычках rx 6к линейки :3 впрочем там все было не так уж и плохо как могло бы быть(бывают  ведь и х2 слоты и х1)

Comment: Так что в конечном итоге, мне можно не беспокоиться и новое поколение видеокарт скорей всего будет работать в полную силу на моей материнке или уже стоит начинать копить на новую материнку?